# When do you give up answering a question

Tags: discussion

This happened to me couple of times recently, where someone asks say a jQuery question with a long piece of code, so I assume the person has a decent understanding of jQuery, so I reply saying "this and that, change your code to below:", they reply "ok, but now I'm getting this error", I reply "Make sure to check your class names", they reply "OK, changed the class names but now I'm getting this error", I reply "make sure this and that", they reply "Yeah, I did but it's too slow, why?", I reply "change this to that", they reply "I don't know where to put that code, is it before onLoad or after jQuery", a question which doesn't make sense, etc, it goes on and I just give up replying, as every reply I post results in another question.

When do you give up trying to help someone? Is it me giving up too soon or some askers just don't know what they're doing?

Comment: Welcome to Chameleon questions... it's a known issue we have... usually after one or two changes I give up

Comment: @Patrice I'm happy to keep answering if they're asking meaningful questions, even if I have to answer 8 times, but some replies to my answer don't even make sense.

Comment: `but now I'm getting this error` == new question.  Period.  Help if you want, but it is better to teach them how to use SO: *thats a new and different problem.  We've fixed the original error, so please post a new question for this one so it gets the attention it deserves*.  This gives you the option to run, run away fast.  Or dig into the new phase.

Comment: @Plutonix Fair point.

Comment: Restricting it to the original question makes the answer(s) and isse clearer for future visitors to understand as opposed to the sweeping saga that can develop in comments with a Chameleon Question.

Comment: My favorite is the questions where OP is getting an error, you tell them how to fix it, then immediately they get another error because their program wasn't getting far enough to encounter the second bug until they fixed the first one. Obviously the reason for this is that your solution is wrong and doesn't work. -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I will answer their replies as long as it is directly relevant to the answer I gave.  As in your example, if my answer had a typo or something that was causing an error, I would correct it and let the OP know.  If they come up with a new problem I leave them a comment asking them to make a new question (if it hasn't already been asked and answered).  More questions to help people find answers to problems is not a bad thing.  Trying to find the question and answer in a comment thread is going to be really hard.

Comment: I see what you mean but they're sort of asking a question related to the answer I gave, not a completely new question. I'll say "instead of this and that use a class in your jQuery selector as in $(".class")" and they'll repy "I used $("#class") but it's not finding anything". Can't really tell them to create a new question for that because there're millions of that already.

Comment: "new error" == new problem and new question.  it is simply somewhat related to the current one.

Comment: @artm I know what you mean.  Like I said, typos and dumb stuff like that is one thing I'm ok with helping with.  It's when it changes from "I can't parse the results from my AJAX call" to "Now my code is creating invalid HTML/CSS and is breaking my site" that they need to ask a new question.